# How can I sort a 2D list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, character

I'm working with a 2D list of numbers similar to the example below I and am trying to reorder the columns:

```
D C B A

1 3 2 0

1 3 2 0

1 3 2 0
```

The first row of the list is reserved for letters to reference each column.
How can I sort this list so that these columns are placed in alphabetical order to achieve the following:

```
D C B A    A B C D

1 3 2 0    0 2 3 1

1 3 2 0    0 2 3 1

1 3 2 0    0 2 3 1
```

I've found examples that make use of lambdas for sorting, but have not found any similar examples that sort columns by characters.

I'm not sure how to achieve this sorting and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Can you show us what code you've got so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume values stored row-by-row in list, like that:

```
a = [['D', 'C', 'B', 'A'],
     ['1', '3', '2', '0'],
     ['1', '3', '2', '0']]
```

To sort this array you can use following code:

```
zip(*sorted(zip(*a), key=lambda column: column[0]))
```

where column[0] - value to be sorted by (you can use column[1](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) etc.)

Output:

```
[('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
 ('0', '2', '3', '1'),
 ('0', '2', '3', '1')]
```

***Note***:
If you are working with pretty big arrays and execution time does matter, consider using numpy, it has appropriate method: [NumPy sort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html)

Answer (score 1):

`zip()` the 2D `list`, sort by the first item, then `zip()` again.

```
>>> table = [['D', 'C', 'B', 'A',],
...          [1, 3, 2, 0,],
...          [1, 3, 2, 0],
...          [1, 3, 2, 0]]
>>> for row in zip(*sorted(zip(*table), key=lambda x: x[0])):
...     print(*row)
...
A B C D
0 2 3 1
0 2 3 1
0 2 3 1
```